# sql search for multiple values

Tags: sql, join, select, subquery, inner-join

I have a `customer` table and an `attribute` table.

The `attribute` table stores which attributes each customer has, so that an attribute that is being added to a customer is entered as a new line.

I need to find customers that have both a `'cash sale'` attribute and an `'email statement'` attribute.

I tried :

```
select distinct customer
where attributename='cash sale'
and attributename='email statement'
```

Comment: So what is the result of your query?

Comment: You're saying attributes are stored in `Attribute` table and querying `Customer` table?

Comment: Please post the structure of tables `customer` and `attribute` so we can provide a fully working solution

Comment: This should be a simple JOIN between your `customer` and `attribute` table.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use two `JOIN`s from table `customer` to table `attribute`, one for each attribute that must be available for the customer.

Assuming that...

- table `customer` has a column named `id` that uniquely identify a customer
- table `attribute` has a column named `customer_id` that is a foreign key to `customer`

... Here is the query that answers your question :

```
SELECT c.id
FROM 
    customer c
    INNER JOIN attribute a1
        ON  a1.customer_id = c.id 
        AND a1.attributename = 'cash sale'
    INNER JOIN attribute a2
        ON  a2.customer_id = c.id
        AND a2.attributename = 'email statement'
```

NB : as `id` is a unique field in the `customer` table, the `DISTINCT` is not needed.

Comment: I believe you meant "... `customer_id` that is a foreign key to `customer`"?

Comment: This can be a single `JOIN` with `a1.attributename IN ('cash sale','email statement')`.

Comment: @stickybit, yes you are correct, thanks for checking... Fixed

Comment: @Shawn : no, the OP wants to make sure that *both* attributes are available for the customer

Comment: @GMB Ah. Missed that. Then yes, the  two joins would be needed. And depending on the size of the data involved and the available indexes, this might be a much more efficient operation than the `EXISTS` with sub-selects.

Answer (score 3):

Use EXISTS to check whether a customer has a certain attribute in the attributes table:

```
SELECT 
  customerid, customername
FROM
  customers c
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM attributes a WHERE a.customerid = c.customerid AND a.attributename = 'cash sale'
  )
  AND 
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM attributes a WHERE a.customerid = c.customerid AND a.attributename = 'email statement'
  )
```

assuming that `customers.customerid` is the id and `attributes.customerid` is the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer exactly without more info about the database schema.
Regardless, you need to join on the two tables and account for fan-out.

Such as (in Oracle syntax):

```
select <customer columns that you want> from customers c
inner join attributes a
on c.customer_id = a.customer_id
where attributename = 'cash sale'
or attributename = 'email statement'
having count(1) = 2
group by <customer columns that you want>
```

This statement will return one or two rows for each customer, with the different attributes appended to the repeated customer columns:

```
select * from customers c
inner join attributes a
on c.customer_id = a.customer_id
where attributename = 'cash sale'
or attributename = 'email statement'
```

The "having" statement limits the data returned to only customers that have two rows (one for each attribute), and the "group by" statement merges the two rows into one.

This assumes:

- there is a unique customer_id primary key column in the customers table.
- the relationship between the customer and attributes table is a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in attribute table, (customerId, attributename) is unique

```
 select *
    from customer c
    where c.customerId IN (
        select a.customerId
        from attribute a
        where a.attributename = 'cash sale'
        or a.attributename = 'email statement'
        group by a.customerId
        having count(a.attributename) = 2
    );
```